# Обновление суммарной стоимости в зависимости от значения "input" с помощью ajax (Laravel)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, input

Есть модальное окно, где пользователь может купить конкретный товар. Перед формами, куда надо ввести данные, я вывожу то, что выбрал пользователь(картинку товара, название, далее идет импут где меняется значение и наконец общая сумма:

CartController:

```
public function modal_order(Request $request, $id){
    $product = Product::find($id);
      return response()->json([
            'name' => $product->name,
            'img' => "/img/products/".$product->cardImage->path,
            'price' => $product->price*$request->qty."$",
       ]);
  }
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.product-icon-container').find('.modal_order').click(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let qty = parseInt($('.inputModal').val());
   $.ajax({
     url: $(this).attr('href'),
     dataType: 'JSON',
     data:{
       qty:qty
   },
   success: function(response) {
     $('.basket-prod-name').html(response.name);
     $('.basketimg').attr('src', response.img);
     $('.totalPrice').html(response.price);
     $('#staticBackdrop').modal('show');
   }
  });
  return false;
 });

});
```

Input:

```
<input type="number" class="inputModal" name="" value="1" min="1" max="100">
```

И если задать стандартное значение в инпуте, то все нормально обсчитывается, но когда я меняю в модальном окне это значение, сумма не изменяется. Понятно, что это из за того, что у меня оно достается с помощью $request, а вот как делать это асинхронно знает кто-нибудь?

Модальное окно bootstrap 4.5.3, которое подключается через @include:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- -->
        <div class="login-form modal-purchase">
            <form action="" method="POST">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="close-modal">&times;</span>
              </button>
              @csrf
                  <h2 class="text-center">Placing order</h2>
                  <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><a href="/"><img class="basketimg mr-1" src=""></a></th>
                        <td><span class="basket-prod-name"></span></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="cols">
                                <input type="number" class="inputModal" min="1" max="100">
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"><h5>Total price:</h5></td>
                        <td><h5 class="totalPrice"></h5></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="" placeholder="Enter your name" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                    @error('name')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong></strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror

                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                      <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-Mail Address" required autocomplete="email">

                      @error('email')
                          <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                              <strong></strong>
                          </span>
                      @enderror

                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                      <input id="phone" type="phone" class="form-control @error('phone') is-invalid @enderror" name="phone" placeholder="phone" required>

                      @error('password')
                          <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                              <strong></strong>
                          </span>
                      @enderror

                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Place order</button>
                 </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Index.blade.php куда модальное окно подключается:

```
@section('tittle', 'Main page')

@section('content')
@include(inc.flash)
@include(inc.modal-order)
<section class="container">
    <h1 class="s2tittle">Leaders of sells</h1>
      <div class="slider">
        @foreach($proditem as $product)
          @foreach($product->products as $item)
            <div class="card">
              <a href="/{{ $product->code }}/{{ $product->url }}/{{ $item->url }}"><img class="card-img-top" src="/img/products/{{ $item->cardImage->path}}" alt="Card image cap"></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <a href="/{{ $product->code }}/{{ $product->url }}/{{ $item->url }}"><h5 class="card-title text-center">{{ $item->name }}</h5></a>
                <div class="prch"><span class="card-text">{{ $item->price }}</span><span class="card-text"><i class="{{ $item->is_available_icon }}"></i>{{ $item->is_available_text }}</span></div><br>
                <div class="prch second">
                <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                <span class="card-text feedback">10 reviews</span>
                </div>
              </div><!--end card-body-->
              <div class="card-footer"></div>
              <div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-handshake"></i><span class="reg">Ordered by 10 people</span><br>
              <div class="product-icon-container" value="Display notification">
                <a href="{{ route('basket-add', [ 'id' => $item->id ]) }}" class="ajaxcartadd scrollOffset btn btn-success mt-2 mb-1">Add to cart</a>
                <a href="{{ route('modal-order', [ 'id' => $item->id ]) }}" class="modal_order btn btn-danger mt-2 mb-1">Buy this item now</a>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div><!--end card-->
          @endforeach
       @endforeach
    </div>
</section>
@endsection
```

Модально окно открывает при нажатии на кнопку "Buy this product now".

Comment: Приведите разметку. И `'price' => $product->price*$request->qty."$",` это то, что вы хотет вставить в `input`?

Comment: @doox911, обновил. `'price' => $product->price*$request->qty."$"` это(суммарная стоимость с учетом количества товара) то, что я вставляю в `<h5 class="totalPrice"></h5>`. А значение из `input`(это количество товара) я беру, потом умножаю его на стоимость одной единицы товара и вывожу результат(суммарная стоимость) в `<h5>`. Но не знаю как сделать это асинхронно(то есть чтобы пользователь взял стрелками добавил/отнял либо вручную ввел количество товара и суммарная стоимость сразу же изменилась).

Comment: Что вы возвращаете с сервера `html` или `json`. Что происходит после клика? Есть какая ошибка? Вы проовали вставлят консоль и смотреть что в респонсе срабатывает ли запрос и сама функция? Есть ли ошибки в консоле. Попробуйте просто без запроса перерисовывать `dom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения:
Для начала нужно добавить кнопке, по которой открывается модальной окно `data-id`.

Затем через `ajax` мы будет вставлять по клике значение `id` текущего товара.

Функция в Controller:

```
public
function modal_order($id) {
    $product = Product::find($id);
    return response() - > json([
        'modalProdId' => $product - > id, //эта строка вставляет текущее значение id
        'name' => $product - > name,
        'img' => "/img/products/".$product - > cardImage - > path,
        'price' => $product - > price
    ]);
}
```

Роут:

```
Route::get('/modal/{id}', [CartController::class, 'modal_order'])->name('modal_order');
```

И сам ajax запрос:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product-icon-container').find('.modal_order').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response) {
                $('.basket-prod-name').html(response.name);
                $('.modal_order').attr('data-id', response.modalProdId); //эта строка вставляет текущее значение `id`
                $('.basketimg').attr('src', response.img);
                $('input[name=inputModal]').val(1);
                $('.totalPrice').html(response.price);
                $('#staticBackdrop').modal('show');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Так же для обновления и подсчета нового значения стоимости функция в Controller:

```
public
function modal_order_update(Request $request, $id) {
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $modalQty = $request - > qty;
    return response() - > json([
        'price' => $product - > price * $modalQty
    ]);
}
```

Роут:

```
Route::get('/modal/update/{id}', [CartController::class, 'modal_order_update'])->name('modal_order_update');
```

И ajax запрос:

```
$('input[name=inputModal]').change(function() {
    let qty = parseInt($('input[name=inputModal]').val());
    let id = $('.card').find('.modal_order').attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/modal/update/' + id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            qty: qty
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('.totalPrice').html(response.price);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/560403)

Comment: @Vanyamba Electronics, я этот же вопрос задавал на англоязычном StackOverflow, дали один из вариантов решения, но он не полностью меня устраивал, взяв некоторую полезную инфу с их ответа я нашел решение и привел его там, чтобы то же самое не копипастить сюда решил просто ссылку скинуть, но в целом  вы правы и на всякий я перенес тот же ответ сюда.

Answer (score -1):

Делайте запрос на сумму, когда меняете значение. Получаете сумму и подставляете её в input

Comment: Возможно я не совсем понятно выразился. Мне как раз таки наоборот нужно. Взять значение из input, на основании этого значения рассчитать сумму и подставить её в нужное место.